# Finding the local/global minima of Shubert function

Tags: na.numerical-analysis, oc.optimization-and-control

Consider the [2D Shubert function](http://www.staff.brad.ac.uk/jpli/research/scga/shubert/shubrt21.htm). As given in that page, the function has 18 global minima and several local minima. How can I find the (x,y) of all these minima? Any help appreciated. If it was a summation (instead of a product), I would have done it by minimizing each individual term. However, I have 0 clue as to how to find the minima in this case.

UPDATE: Before applying any global optimizer, I want to know "theoretically" what are the (x,y) of all the minima. I want to be able to compare the expected and the obtained results

Comment: @Willie: retagged.

Comment: You will need to re-edit, because I have no idea what you mean by knowing (x,y) "theoretically".  You can't mean closed-form.

Comment: Rereading your comment, I see what you are after: you want to be able to 'test' the results.  But that (essentially) requires knowing the answer before computing it...  which is usually exactly what people do when testing scientific software: they run many cases where the answer is already known from some other method, and verify that the new method agrees.  The only alternative is to use a 'proven' method (like interval-based methods!) which have a proof of (partial) correctness, i.e. if they return a result, the result is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At Jacques' cajoling, I'm turning the comments into an answer.

The two dimensional Shubert function is just the product of the one dimensional one by itself. $f(x,y) = g(x)g(y)$ where $g(x) = \sum_{j = 1}^5 j \cos( (j+1)x + j)$ is the 1 dimensional Shubert function. Observe that the local maxima are all positive, and the local minima all negative. So the minima for $f(x,y)$ occur at points $\{(x,y) : g'(x)= g'(y) = 0, f(x,y) < 0\}$. In other words, the minima of $f$ occurs at points where a maximum of $g$ is multiplied against a minimum.

Notice that there are 3 global max/min each of $g$ in the interval (-10,10), and 19 max and 20 min overall. This produces the 760 total local min of $f$ with 18 of them being global. (760 = 2 * 19 * 20, 18 = 2 * 3 * 3)

To find the extrema of the 1-d Shubert function, you evaluate its first derivative, and find that it can be simplified to a degree 6 polynomial in $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$ by using the angle addition formulae. I have not evaluated the computations myself, so cannot tell you whether the expression has a closed-form algebraic solution.

Comment: Thanks a  lot Willie Wong:) Just some clarifications:

"Observe that the local maxima are all positive, and the local minima all negative"- How did you find that? Since each term is a summmation, so a minima will be obtained if ((j+1)x+j) = (2n+1)pi, that is cos(x) = -1, and hence the minima will be -ve and similarly for the positive maxima for which cos(x)=1 ? Pls. clarify.

Comment: To be honest, I just plotted it with wxMaxima. 

Comment: :) Yeah, I just could proceed with my problem because of your answers. I just noted the X-values for 1D from my plot using gnuplot (I had to use a huger number of samples to get an accurate estimation), but my work has progressed. Thanks a ton :)

Comment: @Willie Wong: In 5D, a global minima will be obtained by the combination of 4 global maxima and global minima, right?

If that is true, then we have (3^4 * 3 * 5) global minima. How do I get that? Considering the first four dimensions of a global minima has to come from the 5 global maxima, there are 3^4 possible ways of picking the first 4 dimensions. Now they can be combined with any of the 3 global minima, thus (3^4 * 3) global minima. Again the 4 sets of global maxima from the 5 can be chosen in 5 ways. Hence, a total of (3^4 *3 *5) global maxima. 



Comment: @Willie Wong: Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: @Amit: this is getting rather off the scope of this site, and becoming basic calculus. The point of my answer was that for your f(x) any local extrema is a local max for |f(x)|. So for f(x)f(y)...f(z) the same holds: a local min is a local extremum where the function takes negative values. This implies that it must have an odd number of factors of local min. For it to be global, you need to maximize the absolute value among admissible ones, so if the global max of f(x) > |global min f(x)| then you want only one factor as the min, otherwise as many factors as possible. 

Answer (score 1):

I would use an optimization method based on [interval methods](http://www.cs.sandia.gov/opt/survey/interval.html) to get guaranteed results.  On problems such as this, they tend to converge much faster than traditional methods, and with the added bonus of being guaranteed correct, unlike methods based purely on point evaluations.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think I phrased my question slightly wrong. Before applying any global optimizer, I want to know "theoretically" what are the (x,y) of all the minima. I want to be able to compare the expected and the obtained results. 

Comment: The 2D Shubert function is just the product of two 1D ones. The global minima will be at (x,y) where either x is a global maximum of the 1D Shubert function and y is a global minimum, or vice versa. Here we use the fact that a maximum of the Shubert function is strictly positive, and a minimum is negative. (Three global min/max of the function exists in the interval under consideration, so this gives the 18 global minima.) The local ones can be found analogously by noting that there are 20 local minima and 19 local maxima in the region, which produces the 760 local minima.

Comment: To find the local extrema of the 1D function, note that its derivative can be written as a polynomial in sin(x) and cos(x). Then either the roots have nice closed-form, algebraic expressions, or they don't. 

Comment: @Willie: Good points about the specifics of Shubert functions.  My answer was about the general case.  And, as so often happens, the structure present in special cases means that there is indeed a solution then.  You should turn your comments into an answer!  I would vote it up.